# Delphi XE3 watches that create a new instance of a class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'm new to Delphi and I'm using Rad Studio XE3.

For debug purposes, I'd like to see at runtime what value would have a `TDateTime` variable if it was assigned some value. For example, having `var date : TDateTime`:

```
date := 0
```

So, I was wandering if is it possible to use the watches window for that purpose. I tried something like `TDateTime.Create(0)` or `TDateTime := 0`, but both give erroro messages as output.

Is there a way to do what I need with watches?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1** `0 As TDateTime` does not work too.

Comment: You can watch and modify values, you can even call functions, but I don't believe you can declare new variables during debugging. Although if you're looking only for how to modify value of a declared variable, you can take a look at [`this help topic`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Evaluate_Modify).

Comment: The problem with this case is just that TDateTime(0) is an invalid type cast.

Comment: @TLama Actually, I don't want to _declare_ a new variable, I want to create a new instance of an object and see its value. It's like add a watch in C# or java like: new TDateTime(0). Is it possible in Rad Studio?

Comment: Yes, [`you can create instance of an object`](http://i.imgur.com/K83eNLr.png) in watch list. But `TDateTime` is not an object. `TDateTime` would require a variable and that's what I think it's not possible.

Comment: TDateTime is indeed not an object, actually TDateTime is a Double. The date value is represented by the number of days since 31-12-1899. The decimal value represents the time as part of one day (0.5 = noon).

Comment: The trick here is that a TDateTime watch is displayed in a readable format.

Comment: @UweRaabe Delphi is weirdo. `double(integer)` typecast never worked. Try `TDateTime(0.0)`;

Comment: @Arioch'The No dice there either. I can't make anything work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A watch only works to *watch* existing variables; AFAICT, you can't create new variables to add to the watch window at runtime.

(Also, `TDateTime` isn't an object in Delphi, as others have noted in the comments to your question. It's simply a `double` that encodes the date in the integral portion of the value, and the time in the fractional (decimal) part, oo you can't create a `TDateTime` instance.)

You can use the evaluate/modify window (available when the debugger is at a breakpoint via `View->Debug Windows->Evaluate/Modify` or the right-click menu, `Run->Evaluate/Modify`, or <kbd>Ctrl+F7</kbd>) to evaluate an expression like `DateToStr(0)'. The only way to watch a variable is to actually declare (and use) the variable in your code, and then set a watch on that variable; simply declaring it isn't enough, as the compiler will optimize away unused variables. Also, the function you're evaluating must be actually used somewhere in your code itself, or it won't be available. (The linker doesn't include functions in your executable that aren't actually called in most cases.)

If you only want the variable available when debugging, but not in your release code, you can surround it with `{$IFDEF DEBUG}` (which is pre-defined in the Debug build configuration automatically).

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
var
  CurrDate: TDateTime;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  CurrDate := Date;
  // Use CurrDate so the compiler doesn't eliminate it.
  {$ENDIF}
  // Your other code here as usual
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I believed that TDateTime was an Object (thanks to you all who pointed this is not). The workaround of using "DateToStr" in the evaluate window did the job to me!